# How to assign a default/priority taxonomy to be shown in url in case two taxonomy items are selected

Tags: customization, taxonomy, urls, slug

I have a custom taxonomy (ex. taxonomyfoo) created with CPT UI plugin and assigned this taxonomy to the standard wp post.

I have also used below code to add the taxonomy slug in the url (%taxonomyfoo%/%post-title%/):

```
add_filter('post_link', 'taxonomyfoo_permalink', 10, 3);
add_filter('post_type_link', 'taxonomyfoo', 10, 3);

function taxonomyfoo_permalink($permalink, $post_id, $leavename) {
    if (strpos($permalink, '%taxonomyfoo%') === FALSE) return $permalink;

        // Get post
        $post = get_post($post_id);
        if (!$post) return $permalink;

        // Get taxonomy terms
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'taxonomyfoo');   
        if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms) && is_object($terms[0])) $taxonomy_slug = $terms[0]->slug;
        else $taxonomy_slug = 'taxonomy_z';

    return str_replace('%taxonomyfoo%', $taxonomy_slug, $permalink);
}
```

If I only have two items under taxonomyfoo (taxonomy_z and taxonomy_a), and knowing that the order of taxonomies in wp is alphabetical, if I select both taxonomy_z and taxonomy_a for a single post, it will automatically use taxonomy_a in the url (example.com/taxonomy_a/post-title/).

Is there a way to make taxonomy_z the default/priority url slug in case all taxonomies are selected? Because in some posts I have scenarios when both need to be selected however one is more of a priority to be present the url than the other.

Much thanks!

Comment: You can use a [custom field](https://wordpress.org/support/article/custom-fields/) to set the taxonomy's term slug that you'd like to use in the permalink. For example, the field name could be `taxonomyfoo_slug` and the value would be `taxonomy_z` or whatever is the term slug. And use `get_post_meta()` to get the field value.

Comment: Thank you @SallyCJ! Unfortunately I'm a newbie in programming (so sorry for this). From what I understand you're suggesting to enter the desired slug per post via a custom field? The solution I'm looking for is for a specific taxonomy item to be the default/priority in case it's ticked with other taxonomy items, since my site has thousands of posts so assigning a taxonomy in the custom field per post would be repetitive and taxing.

Also for the get_post_meta() to get the field value, where can I place this in the above code? Thanks so much.

Comment: You can use plugins like [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) to create the field UI without any coding. Are you already using it, or are you familiar with it? And are you using a *custom post type*?

Comment: Thanks @SallyCJ, yes I'm already using ACF and familiar with using it.. I am using post type called "blog" but I am using the taxonomy in question for the standard WP Post..

Comment: Basically I wanted to assign cities to a standard WP post.

For example:
example.com/memphis/post-name

Taxonomy would include: tennessee, memphis, nashville.

If a post needed to be assigned to both nashville & tennessee (since post is applicable statewide and I would also like post to appear under nashville archives), post would be example.com/nashville/post-name, which would be weird because it should be the state of "tennessee" instead of a lower level "nashville" in the url.

If it's possible to assign tennessee as default slug when two options are selected, that would be great!

Comment: In that case, then the custom field is what you'd need since I suppose that "tennessee" is not always "tennessee" - i.e. it could be a different default term for other posts - or other combinations of selected terms, right?

Comment: Thanks! Actually the site is about Tennessee only, so for example for every time "tennessee" is selected together with other of its cities, post should have the url slug of "tennessee" instead of any other Tennessee cities.

Also in case solution is to use custom field for this function, how do I add the meta in the url? Thanks!

Comment: Ok, could you please try the code in my answer? Just change the value of the `$default_slug` to `tennessee` (or whatever the correct slug is) and see if that works for you.

Comment: Great thanks @SallyCJ will check this out. By the way, if taxonomy "nashville" became a parent taxonomy and its neighborhoods "hillsboro" and "greenhills" became its child taxonomies, is there also a way to turn to "nashville" as their default url slug? I'll check out the solution you provided.

Comment: @SallyCJ it actually worked! :) Thanks so much for helping out on this one. By the way what are your thoughts on above question? Or should I create a new post here on stackexchange for this follow up question? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, there is. I'll edit the code soon.

Comment: @SallyCJ your second code also worked! Thanks so much! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The solution I'm looking for is for a specific taxonomy item to be the
>   default/priority in case it's ticked with other taxonomy items

Are you actually looking for something like this:

```php
$default_slug = 'taxonomy_z'; // slug of the default term
if ( ! is_wp_error( $terms ) && ! empty( $terms ) ) {
    $list = wp_list_filter( $terms, array( 'slug' => $default_slug ) );
    if ( ! empty( $list ) ) { // the post **is** in the default term
        // If two or more terms assigned to the post, use the default term's slug.
        $taxonomy_slug = ( count( $terms ) > 1 ) ? $default_slug : $terms[0]->slug;
    } else { // the post is **not** in the default term
        $taxonomy_slug = $terms[0]->slug;
    }
} else { // the post is not in any of the taxonomy's terms; use the default term.
    $taxonomy_slug = $default_slug;
}
```

That would replace this part in your code:

```php
if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms) && is_object($terms[0])) $taxonomy_slug = $terms[0]->slug;
else $taxonomy_slug = 'taxonomy_z';
```

### UPDATE

> if taxonomy "nashville" became a parent taxonomy and its neighborhoods
>   "hillsboro" and "greenhills" became its child taxonomies, is there
>   also a way to turn to "nashville" as their default url slug?

Yes, by storing the parent terms (their slugs) in an array (`$default_slugs` in the below example). However, this means that your posts should not have two parent terms which are in that array. I.e. A post can be in `tennessee` or `nashville`, but not both. Because otherwise, the permalink slug might not be what you expected it to be.

```php
$default_slugs = array( 'tennessee', 'nashville' ); // list of parent terms/slugs
if ( ! is_wp_error( $terms ) && ! empty( $terms ) ) {
    $slugs = wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'slug' );
    $list = array_intersect( $slugs, $default_slugs );
    if ( ! empty( $list ) ) { // the post **is** in a parent term
        // If two or more terms assigned to the post, use a parent term's slug.
        $default_slug = array_shift( $list );
        $taxonomy_slug = ( count( $terms ) > 1 ) ? $default_slug : $terms[0]->slug;
    } else { // the post is **not** in a parent term
        $taxonomy_slug = $terms[0]->slug;
    }
} else { // the post is not in any of the taxonomy's terms; use a default term.
    $taxonomy_slug = 'tennessee';
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks @Sally CJ! let me check this out.

Comment: It actually worked! :)